# php+mysqli while(false !== ($data = $mysqli_res->fetch_assoc)) creates infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, infinite-loop

I wrote an overview for new comments in an admin panel. My code

```
if($res = $db->query("select * from comments where unlocked=0"));
{
    $o = 0; //abortcondition temp
    echo '<div class="newcomments"><a>neuste kommentare: </a><br />';
    //here is the infinite loop
    while(false !== ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) && ++$o < 10)
    {
        if($articles = $db->query("select title from coreless_articles where ID=".$data['article']))
        {
            if(false !== ($article = $articles->fetch_assoc()))
            {
                echo 
                '<div id="comment'.$data['ID'].'">'.$data['from'].' in'.
                ' <a href="article/'.($article['uri']).'#comments">'.$article['title'].'</a>'.
                ' <a href="javascript:;">anzeigen</a>'.
                ' <a href="javascript:;">freischalten</a>'.
                ' <a href="javascript:;">l&ouml;schen</a>'.
                ' <div class="preview" >'.$data['text'].'</div>'.
                '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

creates an infinite loop, if I don't have the $o abort condition. But I want to show all new comments, not just ++$o < n. I use mysqli to access the database.

any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you replace false by NULL(or !== by !=)?

Comment: Also, your code looks vulnerable to both SQL and XSS injections. That's something you probably want to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli_result::fetch_assoc returns NULL when it's empty, not FALSE. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or
>   NULL if there are no more rows.

Just change your test to `NULL !== (etc)`.

(This is pretty confusing because the equivalent function mysql_fetch_assoc() *does* return FALSE.)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you testing for the negative condition? Why don't you simply test for the positive one?

```
while($data = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
 //.....
}
```

Anyway, `@evan`'s explatation why the code creates an infinite loop holds absolutely true.

Comment: That's a bad habit to encourage. While it probably doesn't matter in *this* case, imagine looping over a dataset where `$res->fetch_assoc()` could be an empty array; or if you were looping over an array with `0` or empty strings in it.

Comment: `NULL` or `false` will break the loop. With empty dataset or empty array the code in the loop will never execute. Simply, when the first time the condition is checked, it will evaluate to `false` and never enter the loop. I don't see anything dangerous in this.

Comment: You misunderstand me- what if one of the arrays *in* the data set you're looping over is empty. PHP interprets an empty array as falsy. Your loop will stop at that point. Same if you're looping over a list where some of the **elements** can be `0` or `""` or other falsy values. Nothing **technically** wrong **in this case**- I agree that it won't happen **in this case**- but it's a bad habit.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree that is a bad habit. I am constructing the condition in this way because I know I am iterating over results that come from DB and the rows can never be either empty strings or empty arrays. With your suggestion I have to check the return type of the function I am using and as we can see this can lead to problems :)